# YouTube API unauthorized overlay

Tags: android, youtube

В приложении пытаюсь добавить просмотр видео в новости, формирование разметки новости происходит программно - layout-файла нет (да и быть не может), плеер подгружается, все отлично - но после через секунду после старта видео становится в паузу (причем если открыть его здесь же в полный экран - смотри хоть засмотрись, все работает). Погуглив выяснил что получаю unauthorized overlay.

Новость с видео на экране:
[image: 1]

Код формирующий блок с видео:

```
case "VideoView":
            view = new LinearLayout(context);
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            view.setId(1);
            view.setPadding(0,10,0,0);
            view.bringToFront();

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(1, VideoFragment.newInstance(text)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
```

класс VideoFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;

public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

    private static final String TOU_TUBE_API_KEY = "****";

    public VideoFragment() { }

    public static VideoFragment newInstance(String url) {

        VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("url", url);

        f.setArguments(b);
        f.init();

        return f;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize("TOU_TUBE_API_KEY", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "player error: " + arg1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Может кто-то сталкивался и знает способ победить данную проблему? Пробовал видео выводить в самом верху - проблемы не решило, убирал все отступы - все одно и то же.

**UPD**
Выяснилось что видео останавливается только на моем планшете - на двух других устройствах все в порядке. На планшете Android 5.1

Comment: Попробуйте убрать padding. Проблема с перекрытием чем-либо фрагмента youtube. Оно этого не любит - проверяет, что должны быть такие размеры view, а по факту меньше, и отваливается.

Comment: пробовал - не помогает (да и на телефоне с ними отлично видео идет), скорее всего проблема с ViewPager - если открываю новость с видео из списка, проигрывает без проблем, если новость с видео открывается пролистыванием - также через секунду останавливается. Думаю сделать проще - по началу воспроизведения открывать видео во весь экран.